# To find the max(sum) in MYSQL for a particular id in 2 different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks like[image]

I need the sum of goal of a particular team_id 
for example :
If team_id 16 has scored goal 6 and 2 respectively the sum would be 8 in another new column sum_goal

I am unable to proceed further. Kindly help.

the query which i had tried is :

Select ( match_id, Sum(Goal) From
    (
    Select team1_id ID, team1_goal Goal From match_result_updation
    Union All
    Select team2_id ID, team2_goal Goal From match_result_updation
    )

```
as A)
```

FROM

(SELECT 
 c.tournament_id , g.*
FROM team_trophies d 
INNER JOIN 
tournament_match e
ON
e.tournament_id = d.tournament_id
INNER JOIN
tournament_scheduling c 
ON
c.tournament_id = e.tournament_id 
INNER JOIN 
matches f 
on 
f.match_id = c.id
INNER JOIN 
match_result_updation g 
ON
g.match_id = f.id
WHERE
f.match_type = 'tournament'
and 
d.tournament_id = 1) as p
Group By match_id

From the second select to id = 1 i am getting the output as in the attachment picture but I am unable to find the sum for goals each team_id.
also if teamid 16 or 17 either team1 or team2 accordingly sum of the goals will be calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be to put them in like columns and then sum.
EDIT Any SQL Engine

```
Select ID, Sum(Goal) From
    (
    Select Team1_ID ID, Team1_Goal Goal From Table
    Union All
    Select Team2_ID ID, Team2_Goal Goal From Table
    ) A
Group By ID
```

ps This kind of workaround would not be necessary if the table design were normalized.

Comment: we are using MYSQL.

Comment: I have tried using the given above answers in my initial code to get the sum of the goals of a particular teamid but didnt get a proper result set.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query it will help to sum of goal

```
select team1_id, sum(team1_goal) as sum_goal from `table` group by `team1_id`;
```

Comment: That is true If the id 16 is on the team2_id then how would you find the sum goal count ??

Answer (score 0):

We can do like this also....

```
select team1_id, sum(team1_goal) as sum_goal from `table` group by `team1_id`
union all
select team2_id, sum(team2_goal) as sum_goal from `table` group by `team1_id`;
```

If you want to sum again then can use like this

```
select t.team_id, sum(t.sum_goal) as total_goal from (
  select team1_id as team_id, sum(team1_goal) as sum_goal from `table` group by `team1_id`
  union all
  select team2_id as team_id, sum(team2_goal) as sum_goal from `table` group by `team1_id`
) as t group by t.team_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select ID, Sum(Goal) From
(
Select Team1_ID ID, Team1_Goal Goal From Table
Union All
Select Team2_ID ID, Team2_Goal Goal From Table
)l,
table_name Group By ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version:

```
SELECT SUM(nr) 
FROM (
    (SELECT sum(team1_goal) as nr FROM goals WHERE team1_id = 16)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT sum(team2_goal) as nr FROM goals WHERE team2_id = 16)
)
sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT team1_id AS Team_ID , sum(team1_goal) as Team_Goal       
FROM 
teams GROUP BY team1_id
UNION
SELECT team2_id AS Team_ID  , sum(team2_goal) as Team_Goal
FROM teams GROUP BY team2_id
```

This will create one table with the ID of each team and the total number of goals made by each team ID